# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 linking facebook sdk

Tags: ios

I am trying to link the facebook library to my app but i am getting this very strange error:

[image]

what does this mean? I got this to work on another app, the files and code are the same...

Comment: It looks like the facebook library is either not being built in the first place or not being linked…  Does the facebook-ios-sdk target appear in the target dependencies of your app target, and is `libfacebook_ios_sdk.a` included in your app target's Link Binary With Libraries build phase?

Comment: there is no libfacebook_ios_sdk.a file

Comment: Sorry, I guess you might be including the facebook code in a different way than I normally do…  Are you linking against `FacebookSDK.framework` (from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/), or have you included the facebook-ios-sdk project (from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) as a subproject of your app's Xcode project?  Something else?  Maybe you've just included facebook SDK source files directly in your app's Xcode project?

Comment: I have included the files: facebook.h .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is from the linker.  When you compile your code, the compiler can find declarations for all the functions that you need, because you're including the facebook header (facebook.h).  But when it comes time to link your program, the linker tries and fails to find compiled versions of those facebook methods.  You need to bring the facebook SDK into your project and link against it.

The way I'm going to recommend linking against the Facebook SDK is actually one I haven't tried before, but it looks like the simplest way to get your project building:

1. Download and install the FacebookSDK framework from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/).
2. Drag the `FacebookSDK.framework` bundle, which will end up in ~/Documents/FacebookSDK into your Xcode project.
3. When given the option, choose not to "Copy items into destination group's folder" and make sure that your application target is selected in the "Add to targets" section.

You may have to change your current `#import/#include` lines.  To see the facebook methods from the framework you just imported, you should import like:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

Comment: thanks, this removed most of the errors, but I realised I also had to add the address.framework